# dns website down after moving the different server

Tags: vps, dns-zone

One of the website ie intralifeindia.com was moved from dedicated server to vps server. So i just changed the ip address from domain controls. After doing so emails are working but website not appearing. on browser shows dns error. On Whoishosting shows correct name servers & ip address.

Can anyone point what the problem is?
What should i try changing?

current name servers are: ns1.intralfiendia.com
ns2.intralifeindia.com

Ip Address: 97.74.237.24

Comment: Everything looks fine from here. You are probably just dealing with a stale cache on your resolver, which you'll just have to wait out.

Answer (score 0):

Your site works properly on new IP address. I think the problem is in DNS cached server on client side. Change dns server to Google's 8.8.8.8 on client PC or restart your router.

In addition. It isn't good idea to use one dns server as ns1.intralfiendia.com and ns2.intralfiendia.com. But this hasn't any relations to your problem.